# Accessing Resource Unit Agent variables from main

Tags: anylogic

I created an Agent Type and specified the property of "Use in flowcharts as: Resource Unit".
I created a variable called "Location" of type double.
In a release block, in the "On release" field, when I write unit.Location, Location variable is not identified and I get an error.

How to access variables from the resource agent unit in a seize/release block?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always typecast (i.e. enforce) it using `((MyAgentType)unit).Location`

However, you must make sure that all resource units being released in that Release block are of that `MyAgentType` type, else you will get a runtime error.

PS: Java convention has variable names in lower case, best keep those ;)